# Кривой вывод dataframe в консоль PyCharm

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

[image: Вывод csv файла]

Я предпологаю что проблема быть может в настройках среды разработки. Но самостоятельно ничего не нашёл. Быть может данные сохраняю не так как-то.Но это врядли.

[image: а это уже parquet формат, тут вообще -2 колонки]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

очень раздражает и отвлекает. Хотелось бы найти и решить проблему. Спасибо

Comment: а код прикрепите которым сохраняете

Comment: добавил в топик

Comment: pprint пробовали?

Comment: в моём случае не помогло

Comment: А как выводите то? Посмотрите есть ли настройки шрифта для консоли, попробуйте выбрать для консоли **моноширинный** шрифт, например `Courier` (`Courier New`). Сейчас у вас видимо используется какой-то **пропорциональный** шрифт, в нём **ширина разных букв разная**, поэтому вёрстка текстовых таблиц "едет". Для нормального вывода таких таблиц нужен **моноширинный** шрифт.

Comment: Отлично! Сработало, спасибо. А вот Паркет по прежнему теряет 2 колонки где-то, наверно вопрос уже к реализации больше.

Comment: Оформлю тогда ответом )  Хотя может это дубль, но искать лень

Comment: На будущее: [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите есть ли там настройки шрифта для консоли, попробуйте выбрать для консоли **моноширинный** шрифт, например `Courier New`. Сейчас у вас видимо используется какой-то **пропорциональный** шрифт, в нём **ширина разных букв разная**, поэтому вёрстка текстовых таблиц "едет". Для нормального вывода таких таблиц нужен моноширинный шрифт.